# Should I mock the ControllerContext to unit test my JsonNetResult data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, json.net

I am using the JsonNetResult class from here in my asp.net mvc 4.0 project:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

How can I unit test wether my c# classes are converted correctly to json format?

The Json conversion is executed in the ExecuteResult method which seem to be impossible to

mock according to www.

Some people even say this is too much mock effort just for the json testing.

Some people say why not directly test the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data); method.

I would be grateful to hear some professional advises about that topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if your C# class can be serialized, then try serializing it directly, remember unit testing focuses on testing one particular operation, that link you provided does several things. In order to unit test it you would have to create a method that does most of the work given the current state, rather than using implicit state.

To serialize it directly, just call the contents of `if (Data != null)` giving it the information you want to give. Note that one piece of information you will need to give it is the stream to write to, since it writes to the `Response` directly.

Comment: you mean I should directly call the Json.NET serializer/deserializer? And about the stream to write: For me it seems I have to mock the HttpContext.Response. What do you think?

Comment: @Elisa: No reason to mock the Response, it is just a stream, a `MemoryStream` would allow you to analyze the results without as much work.

Comment: ok, but my json will always be string, how can I compare my List<Person> with a string? I do not want to parse the json string...

Comment: @Elisa: As with any unit testing, you have a predetermined input and output. So a list of Phil, John, Carl, and a JSON string that represents that. You may run into problems with extra whitespace, but you can always remove all the whitespace before comparing.

Comment: I have a pre-determined input yes. But the output is the json string determined by the serializer. And this serializer is only called when the ExecuteResult is called, which can not be done easily if at all... I think I will test my JsonNetResult with QUnit which makes most sense like here: http://www.bradygaster.com/Testing-ASPNET-MVC-with-QUnit-Part-1